# Who are these users?

Tags: discussion, migration, users, deleted-users

There is a user [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/339/732) who is labeled as "Aaron1". I assume he was here before the migration which is why he doesn't appear like a normal user (he was normal [before migration](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328191852/https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues) ).

However, there are other users here who also were unregistered users before the migration, such as [SimchasTorah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/87/simchastorah), who while were unregistered, kept their "user page".

On the other hand, people who were deleted (at least now), got their name removed and replaced with a number (such as [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13984/taking-a-concubine-pilegesh-today).

What is going on?

---

**I AM NOT ASKING TO KNOW WHAT HAPPENED TO ANY PARTICULAR USER. I JUST WANT TO KNOW ABOUT THE CLASS**

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1120/759

Answer (score 1):

While I can't say for certain, I'm pretty sure these are user accounts that have been deleted.